# How to create a subquery that uses listagg in JPA repository?

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, listagg

Using JPA specification classes or predicate builder. How can I convert this WHERE clause?
I am using an oracle db.

```
WHERE (SELECT listagg(reject_cd,':') within group (order by order_no) as rejectList 
FROM REJECT_TABLE WHERE ID = transactio0_ id group by id) like '%06%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LISTAGG` function is highly specific to Oracle, and is not supported by JPQL.  However, you can still use a native query here, e.g.

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT ... WHERE (SELECT LISTAGG(reject_cd,':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_no) AS rejectList FROM REJECT_TABLE WHERE ID = transactio0_ id GROUP BY id) LIKE '%06%'"
    nativeQuery = true)
Collection<SomeEntity> findAllEntitiesNative();
```

Another option here might be to find a way to avoid needing to use `LISTAGG`.  But, we would need to see the full query along with sample data to better understand your requirement.